# The man whose / that company is hiring employees

Tags: relative-pronouns, relative-clauses

Can I use the first sentence in lieu of the second?

> 1.Let me introduce you to the man **that** his company is hiring employees
>
> 2.Let me introduce you to the man **whose** company is hiring employees

If both are used, which one is more common?
Does one seem more weird than the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that only

> Let me introduce you to the man whose company is hiring employees

is correct, if you wanted to rewrite your first sentence to avoid *whose* you could make it

> Let me introduce you to the man who owns the company hiring employees

Comment: Ahh, but do we know if the man is an employee or the employer? I agree it's more likely to be the second, but we do not know who for certain.

Comment: Seeing as 'whose' is a possessive (as an employee I don't think I possess the company for which I work) pronoun, I would think he's the owner - but I see your point, do you have a suggestion to improve my answer?

Comment: Just specify that if the person being presented is the boss (employer) than using *who owns* is acceptable. If the person being presented is a chief executive, or market manager (etc.) than another solution should be used to avoid ambiguity.